# setInterval y setTimeout deja de funcionar si no estoy en su pagina

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

Es una **funcion** que valida que cada 30 segundos de el **setInterval** mande una petición
pero cuando el **SetInterval** o el **timeout** esta inactiva no envía la petición

***¿alguna forma de que cuando la ventana este inactiva funcione de igual forma?***

```
const minutes_sum = this.end.getMinutes();

      this.end.setMinutes(minutes_sum + Math.floor(this.minutes));
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        const now = new Date();

        const distance = this.end.getTime() - now.getTime();
        if (distance < 0) {
          this.$emit("end", true);
          clearInterval(this.timer);
          return;
        }
        const days = Math.floor(distance / this._days);
        const hours = Math.floor((distance % this._days) / this._hours);
        const minutes = Math.floor((distance % this._hours) / this._minutes);
        const seconds = Math.floor((distance % this._minutes) / this._seconds);
        const totalMilliseconds = Math.floor(distance);
        if (seconds == 30) {
          this.$emit("addMinutes", now);
        }
        this.displayMinutes = this.formatNum(minutes);
        this.displaySeconds = this.formatNum(seconds);
        this.displayHours = this.formatNum(hours);
        this.displayDays = this.formatNum(days);
        this.$emit("progress", {
          totalMilliseconds,
          days,
          hours,
          minutes,
          seconds,
        });
      }, 1000);
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que está "inactivo"?

Comment: minimizar el navegador y que el contador siga corriendo

Answer (score 1):

Se refiere a que el `setInterval` y `setTimeout` sigan funcionando aunque el usuario no esté en la página ¿no?

Los navegadores **impiden** que nuestro programa se siga ejecutando en segundo plano, motivos de seguridad y calidad de navegación, ya que la cuestión es: **si el usuario no la está usando, ¿por qué seguirla corriendo?**
Tendrás que utilizar otras técnicas de desarrollo para lograr tu objetivo, tales como hacer que tú sitio web sea [Single-Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) o hacer uso de la API [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) para, no sé, de alguna forma, cuando cambies de página continuar con tu ejecución con la misma información de la página anterior.

Así que si entendí bien su pregunta, la respuesta es que **no**, no hay forma de mantener nuestra ventana ni nuestro código funcionando sin estar en él.